# Setting JDK Path for make OS X

Tags: java, macos, java-8, gnu-make, android-source

I am trying to build Android AOSP on Mac OS X 10.13.6

When running `make` it outputs

```
build/core/config.mk:601: *** Error: could not find jdk tools.jar at /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/../lib/tools.jar, please check if your JDK was installed correctly.  Stop.
```

`JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_JAVA_HOME` are both set to the directory of my JDK installation:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I know that the files under `System/Library/.../Commands` are stubs pointing to the correct JDK installation but `make` tries to find the `tools.jar` in this directory, too.

Is there a way to tell `make` to search in the right directory?

**EDIT**

Error appears in config.mk:601

```
# We may not have the right JAVA_HOME/PATH set up yet when this is run from envsetup.sh.
ifneq ($(CALLED_FROM_SETUP),true)
HOST_JDK_TOOLS_JAR:= $(shell $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/find-jdk-tools-jar.sh)

ifneq ($(HOST_JDK_TOOLS_JAR),)
ifeq ($(wildcard $(HOST_JDK_TOOLS_JAR)),)
$(error Error: could not find jdk tools.jar at $(HOST_JDK_TOOLS_JAR), 
please check if your JDK was installed correctly)
endif
endif
```

But when running `find-jdk-tools-jar.sh` it outputs the correct path, where the tools.jar is indeed located. So make uses some other fallback?

Comment: `make` doesn't need to know where Java is. The command running at `build/core/config.mk:601` does

Comment: Try setting: export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home) inside your ~/.profile. You can use particular version (e.g. java_home -v 1.8).

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set correctly, `java_home -v 1.8` returns the same path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX, /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/ is not where JDK root is.  JDK install home is usually /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk[whatever you have installed].jdk/Contents/Home

You need to configure your JAVA_HOME correctly.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: Whatever command is running at line 601 is incorrectly picking location of tools.jar.  What's located at line 601 of your make file?  I think it's using the path of the java binary as a way to figure out classpath instead of using JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I added the associated lines of the config.mk in my post. It seems that the makefile gets another directory from the `find-jdk-tools-jar.sh` than me when I run the script manually. Adding a printout to the makefile, I see that the variable `HOST_JDK_TOOLS_JAR` is `System/Library/.../Commands`. Running the script manually returns the correct `/Library/Java/.../Contents/Home`. 
Why does it return different outputs?

Comment: Is the env not setup correctly while script is running (a fork or under a different user?).  Add echo $JAVA_HOME to there or inside find-jdk-tools-jar.sh, I suspect the issue is found in there as the script is assuming that $JAVA_HOME/bin is the directory where it finds java but that's not true in OSX.  This explains why ../lib/tools.jar is found in the error.  You need to fix t he find-jdk-tools-jar.sh to correctly detect JAVA_HOME.

Comment: You were right. JAVA_HOME was not set for all users and I ran `make` as sudo so it used a fallback. Now it is getting the right path. Thanks!